# Add CCButton programmatically

Tags: ios, spritebuilder

I am trying to adding `CCButton` in my Scene. I am using Sprite builder.Here is my code.

```
CCButton *btnTest = [[CCButton alloc]initWithTitle:@"BNB test"];
    [btnTest.label setName:@"Test"];
    btnTest.position = ccp(150.0f, 150.0f);

    [self addChild:btnTest];
```

It's not showing on the scene. What may be the reason?

Comment: @DhavalBhadania Its is not showing on the scene.

Answer (score 0):

try this way,i used it for back button ,below code it work fine:

```
CCButton *backButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"[ Back ]" fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];
backButton.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
backButton.position = ccp(0.95f, 0.95f); // Top Right of screen
[backButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(BackClicked:)];
[self addChild:backButton];
```

may it will help you...

Happy coding... :)

Comment: check this one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023663/ccmenuitemsprites-alternative-in-cocos2d-v3/22023961#22023961

Answer (score 0):

The interface on CCButton was a bit not smooth IMHO so I wrote a category.

```
@implementation CCButton (additions)
+(id)buttonWithImagenamed:(NSString*)imagename block:(void(^)(id sender))block {
    CCSpriteFrame* spriteframe = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:imagename];
    NSAssert(spriteframe != nil, @"nil spriteframe for imagename: %@", imagename);
    CCButton* button = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"" spriteFrame:spriteframe];
    button.block = block;
    return button;
}
@end
```

This needs to be emphasized: "imagename" must be relative, so if you put it into a folder like "graphics/myimage.png", you need to specify `@"graphics/myimage.png"` in code. Only `@"myimage.png"` will NOT work in this case.